# Bash script and stdin

Tags: bash, stdin

I am having a C program which requires to read from stdin. This is one of the requirements, and it cannot change.

I have written a simple bash script that creates all the directories I want, handles the output etc. and also compiles and runs my program.

When I run my program it waits for the user to give an input from the stdin :

I want to be able to give that input from the bash - so do not let the user give the input (there is a reason for that). So ideally, I want somehow the input to be visible to the user but given from the script.

If I write something like this :

```
./task2
cat <<< "my input here"
```

It runs the task, and the cat command runs when the task has finished. I want somehow to enforce that cat whenever the program requires input from the user.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try `./task2 <<< "my input here"`?

Comment: see it: 

[How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use `tee` for this purpose. In the Bash script, let's assume the following line runs your compiled C program:

```
./my_program
```

Replace that with:

```
printf "%s\n" "my input here" | tee /dev/tty | ./my_program
```

This will print `my input here` to your terminal device *and* pipe it to `./my_program` on its stdin so it can read it.

Comment: Thanks, this one worked. But What if I want the input to be also printed out on terminal?

Comment: @ghostrider Sorry, I thought the `tee` I had written would do that. Please see the update.